# configure GitLab suggested link to repo

Tags: git, docker, gitlab, synology

I need to highlight I am not a command line pro. I am on some advanced -ish level but in no way power user of the terminal.
I installed GitLab on my Synology Docker (model 1618+) the vanilla way (following out of the box prompts)
Also out of the box, GitLab gives the wrong repo address. for example:

```
ssh://git@localhost:30001/mark/repo.git
```

Burning through tons of online blogs I figure out how to make the git work.
I remapped Docker port 30001 to 2224 for GitLab container and use Synology IP address

```
192.168.1.245 instead of localhost (localhost points to 127.0.0.1)
```

so in order for it to work each new project, I need to change this (example)

```
ssh://git@localhost:30001/mark/repo.git <- provided by GitLab
```

to something like

```
ssh://git@192.168.1.245:2224/mark/repo.git
```

Since it works perfectly with these small changes is there a way to make GitLab conjure links in this format each time I initiate a new project?

```
ssh://git@192.168.1.245:2224/mark/repo.git
```

My goal is to make GitLab suggest appropriate git address ready to copy and paste to the terminal with each newly created project.
Could you explain in lamens terms how to get to and change appropriate config files?

Thank you in advance, Mark

Answer (score 0):

You need to set this 2 values inside gitlab configuration (file gitlab.rb)

this for the name of the url

```
external_url "https://your-domain-or-ip"
```

and this for the ssh external port

```
gitlab_rails['gitlab_shell_ssh_port'] = 22-your-ssh-port-number
```